# PDO connection object cannot be seen in a call back function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

I've got a login project with an index.php page calling the loggin functions from another script file core.inc.php depending on the connection script connect.inc.php which were required in the index.php page 
the core.inc.php cannot see the the connection object throwing an undeffied variable error ..... why ? 
tried to test the $conn object by print_r() and didn't work and throw the undefined var error ....
please help 
here's the index.php code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home page</title>
</head>
<?php 
require("connect.inc.php");
require("core.inc.php");

if(loggedin()){
 echo 'Welcome ' . getuserfield('fname').' ' . 
 getuserfield('surname') .' <a href="logout.php">Logout!</a>';

}
else {include("loginform.inc.php"); echo "<a href='register.php'> Register! </a>";}

?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the connect.inc.php file :

```html
<?php 

define("MYSQL_HOST", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=a_database;charset=utf8");
define("MYSQL_USER", "root");
define("MYSQL_PASS", "123456");

try{
 $conn = new PDO(MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASS);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE,PDO::CASE_LOWER);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
 echo $e-> getMessage();
}
?>
```

and at last the core.inc.php page :

```html
<?php
// to create a login session
ob_start();
session_start();
// define variable to the login form
$current_file =$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

//define the referer where the command comes from
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
 $http_referer= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}

//check if logged in or not
function loggedin(){
 if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
  return true;
 }
 else{return false;}
 
}
////////////////
function getuserfield($field){
 $sql = "SELECT `$field` FROM `users_tb` WHERE `id`='" .$_SESSION['user_id']. "'";
 echo "connection : " ; print_r($conn);
 if(@$run = $conn->query($sql)){
  echo "table connected";
  if ($sql_result = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   echo $run_result[$field]; 
   //return $sql_result[$field]; 
  }
  else {return "Unknown";}
 }
}

?>
```

the problem is that the connection $conn object cannot be seen in the core.inc.file throw the getuserfield($field) function callback 
what's wrong with that ? 
please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$conn` object is not visible in the `getuserfield` function because inside a function you cannot access variables that are defined outside by default. You need to make the variable accessible by using the `global` keyword:

```
function getuserfield($field){
  global $conn;
  /* ... */
}
```

Although that will solve your problem, I would advice against using `global`, your code will get messy and hard to debug. A cleaner way would be to create a class that handles your database operations, and inside this class you could have the connection stored in a static variable:

```
class MyDB {
  public static $conn;

  public static function connect() {
    try{
      self::$conn = new PDO(MYSQL_HOST,MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASS);
      self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
      self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      self::$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CASE,PDO::CASE_LOWER);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}

MyDB::connect();
```

This way you can access the connection object everywhere without using `global` with `MyDB::$conn`